# In WPF is there a way to determine if another control captures the mouse?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a control in my application that needs to know when any other control in the visual tree captures the mouse.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [Mouse.GotMouseCapture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.mouse.gotmousecapture.aspx) attached event.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window {
    public MainWindow() {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    static MainWindow() {
        EventManager.RegisterClassHandler(typeof(UIElement), Mouse.GotMouseCaptureEvent, new MouseEventHandler(MainWindow_GotMouseCapture));
    }
    static void MainWindow_GotMouseCapture(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) {
        // e.OriginalSource is a captured element
    }
}
```

Note, that the captured element is available via the [Mouse.Captured](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.mouse.captured.aspx) static property.

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer.  Although I'm not yet sure if I can use it.  The control that wants to know if the mouse is captured is deep down in the visual tree and isn't able to register an event-handler at such a high level.

Comment: I see what you mean, you aren't using the MainWindow at all to register the event.  So maybe this is the answer I need, I'll look into it again.

Comment: Is there any way to unregister the class handler?

Comment: There is no way to unregister the class handler, but it is not needed in the most cases